Bayesian regression for correcting small sample sizes
I have a problem where I have a sample of 5 data points: $(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),(x_3, y_3),(x_4, y_4),(x_5, y_5)$.
I want to fit a regression model through this data and understand the statistical association of $x$ on $y$ , but this is likely not possible with such little data. However, I have prior knowledge that $y$ increases as $x$ increases. Thus, I was hoping that I could somehow incorporate this prior knowledge using a Bayesian model that could in part compensate for this small sample size.
In my opinion, this model would result in:

$y$ increasing along with $x$ increasing
uncertainty proportional to the small sample size


Here is my attempt to derive the model and show that it meets the beliefs I have about the data. Doing some readings, it seems like the following prior choices are popular choices in linear regression:
Model:
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \epsilon$$
$$\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$
Priors:
$$\beta_0 \sim N(\mu_0, \tau_0^2)$$
$$\beta_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \tau_1^2)$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim \text{InverseGamma}(a, b)$$
Likelihood:
$$p(y|X, \beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2) \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$$
Posterior Distribution:
$$p(\beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2|y, X) \propto p(y|X, \beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2) \cdot p(\beta_0) \cdot p(\beta_1) \cdot p(\sigma^2)$$

Here is my justification of the model properties:

If we choose $\mu_1 > 0$, we are expressing a prior belief that the slope is positive, which means y tends to increase as x increases.
The larger we set $\mu_1$, the stronger our prior belief in a positive relationship.

For example, if we set $\mu_1 = 2$, we're saying that our prior belief is that, on average, y increases by 2 units for every 1 unit increase in x.
The same argument can be made for the strength of the prior belief: The $\tau_1^2$ parameter controls the variance of our prior for $\beta_1$. This reflects our uncertainty about the exact value of $\beta_1$:

A smaller $\tau_1^2$ indicates a stronger prior belief (less uncertainty).
A larger $\tau_1^2$ indicates a weaker prior belief (more uncertainty).

For instance:
$$\beta_1 \sim N(2, 0.5^2)$$
This prior says we believe the slope is likely positive (centered at 2), but we're not extremely certain (there's still some spread around 2).

I tried to show this a bit more formally:
In Bayesian linear regression, the posterior distribution for $\beta_1$ (assuming known variance) is given by:
$$\beta_1 | X, y \sim N(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$$
$$\mu_n = \frac{\tau_1^2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i + \sigma^2 \mu_1}{\tau_1^2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sigma^2}$$
$$\sigma_n^2 = \frac{\sigma^2 \tau_1^2}{\tau_1^2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sigma^2}$$
Here, $n$ is the sample size, $\mu_1$ and $\tau_1^2$ are the prior mean and variance for $\beta_1$, and $\sigma^2$ is the known error variance.
We can see that playing with different values of $\sigma_n^2$ (the posterior variance, which represents our uncertainty) changes with sample size:
As $n$ increases, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ increases. Looking at the formula for $\sigma_n^2$:
$$\sigma_n^2 = \frac{\sigma^2 \tau_1^2}{\tau_1^2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sigma^2}$$
We can see that as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ increases, the denominator increases, causing $\sigma_n^2$ to decrease.
More formally, assume $x_i$ are independently drawn from a distribution with variance $V(X)$. Then:
$$E[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2] = nV(X)$$
Substituting:
$$\sigma_n^2 \approx \frac{\sigma^2 \tau_1^2}{\tau_1^2 nV(X) + \sigma^2}$$
As $n$ approaches infinity:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma^2 \tau_1^2}{\tau_1^2 nV(X) + \sigma^2} = 0$$
We can also express $\sigma_n^2$ in terms of $n$:
$$\sigma_n^2 \approx \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\sigma^2 \tau_1^2}{V(X)\tau_1^2 + \sigma^2/n}$$
This last idea shows that the posterior variance is approximately inversely proportional to the sample size $n$. As $n$ increases, the uncertainty ($\sigma_n^2$) decreases proportionally. This demonstrates that the uncertainty in our estimate of $\beta_1$ decreases as we gather more data (proportional to $1/n$).

Mathematically, the manipulations makes sense to me. But is this a strong argument that shows regression models on small sample sizes can improve when using Bayesian inference compared to Non-Bayesian? Apart from a simulation study (e.g. randomly take a sample of 5 points, fit OLS regression, fit bayesian model, repeat - and compare results from both to truth) - can anything else be shown suggesting the advantages of Bayesian models when confronted with small sample sizes?

While I am a fan of Bayes, I think it is important to note that 5 data points just don't allow for strong conclusions in almost any context. Yes, you can demonstrate how the results change with changing prior and that might have some use, but in the end we either need more data or get comfortable with not being able to make a strong conclusion.

The OP says "I have prior knowledge that  increases as  increases", then that implies the slope of the regression line is non-negative: $\beta_1 >= 0$. Therefore, a Gaussian (normal) prior is inappropriate to capture this important info. Rather, consider a non-negative prior for $\beta_1$, such as $Gamma(k, \theta)$ for example.
